# Why does freeing a bad object pointer throw EPrivilege instead of EAccessViolation?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, access-violation

Why do i get an "`EPrivilege - Privileged instruction`" when I execute this procedure instead of `Access Violation`?

```
{$Warnings OFF}
procedure TFrmMyTest.mnuCrashMeClick(Sender: TObject);
var t: TStringList;
begin
 FreeAndNil(t);
end;
{$Warnings ON}
```

I know that I try to free an object that points randomly in memory. But I expect to get an access violation and not "Privileged instruction".

(Don't worry I don't intend to use the code above in a real program.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you will get an access violation and sometimes you will get `EPrivilege` and no doubt there are other modes of failure. And even sometimes the code will appear to work and the crash will happen later. It all depends on what value happens to be in `t` when you call `Free` on it.

Answer (score 9):

`FreeAndNil` calls the non virtual method `Free`. Which first checks for `nil`(the variable likely isn't `nil`) and then calls the virtual destructor `Destroy`.

Calling a virtual method means looking at the beginning of an object to get the virtual-method-table(VMT). This can throw an access violation. But if the object is in allocated memory, it will instead return an undefined pointer as VMT.

Next a pointer sized value is read at a certain offset from the VMT. This once again can throw an access violation or return an undefined pointer.

Finally the memory where this pointer points is executed. And if it happen to contain invalid code, you get some variant of an invalid instruction exception.